# how to show the 3d-text that I made before in 3ds max by using Away3d?

Tags: 3dsmax, away3d

I made model my using 3ds max, then I export .max to .dae. But I have a problem. The texts which I made before don't appear. I am just wondering, is there any additional syntax to show the text?

Like I did before , I added this syntax below to show the model's animation (such as rotating and moving)

```
import away3d.animators.Animator;
import away3d.animators.BonesAnimator;
```

and then

```
this.modelAnimatorMars = modelMars.animationLibrary.getAnimation("default").animator as BonesAnimator;
```

(modelAnimatorMars = since I made Mars model)

There must be that syntax to show the animation. For the TEXT, I am wondering is there any additional syntax that must I add again?

Thank you

Aksel